# Toggle view with ng-click and ng-if

Tags: angularjs

How do I toggle the view of an article by clicking a `<button>`?

```
<button ng-click="/* change view and button label */">Label</button>
<article ng-if="/* */">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
</article>
<article ng-if="/* */">
    <input type="text" value="{{title}}">
    <textarea>{{content}}</content>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain one `scope` variable `showInputsArticleWithInput` & do toggle it on click of `button` using `ng-click` directive.

As you want to change your button text for that you could use `ng-bind` directive with expression like `ng-bind="showInputsArticleWithInput? 'Edit': 'Close'"`

**Markup**

```
<button type="text" ng-click="showInputsArticleWithInput = !showInputsArticleWithInput"
ng-bind="showInputsArticleWithInput? 'Edit': 'Close'"></button>
<article ng-if="!showInputsArticleWithInput">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
</article>
<article ng-if="showInputsArticleWithInput">
    <input type="text" value="{{title}}">
    <textarea>{{content}}</content>
</article>
```

Comment: And how do I change the label of the button? i.e. "edit" / "close"